# CSS won't connect to .jsp file (using STS)

Tags: java, css, spring, eclipse

Please help! I'm connecting exactly the same way I've done for another project that worked. I've searched StackOverflow and the internet but still can't find a remedy.

Things I've tried :

- Restarting the project and STS
- webapp>resources>css>main.css Paths
- link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css"
- /css/main.css  (with "/")
- css/main.css (without "/")

I'm stumped and I've spent way more time than reasonable trying to figure it out. Big thanks in advance =)

This is how I have it structured:-

[image: project setup]

Comment: You know that the line is commented-out and will not fetch a css-file?

Comment: The line above link href=css/style.css rel="stylesheet"... should, right? I commented it out bc I was trying a million things.

Comment: What error message are you getting? How are you determining that it's not "connecting" (what does that actually mean)?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that none of the CSS is showing up when I go to localhost8080. There are no error messages. When I manually enter < style > in the head of the .jsp file, the changes (e.g. font, color, etc.) show up.

Answer (score 4):

Few points:-

You need to configure the **resources** location in your configuration.

Have you marked the **`src/main/resources`** folder correctly as a resource folder?

Can you or did you try with **`/static/css/style.css`**?

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that value is not set to pageContext.request.contextPath. Try giving absolute path(complete path of the css file). Where did you set the value of pageContext.request.contextPath?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a catch all @RequestMapping which was rerouting to the home page. I thought it would take care of 404 errors. Instead it would never route to my CSS files. Doh! Rookie mistake.

When I commented that out, my CSS showed up. I appreciate all the help!!!

@Controller

//@RequestMapping("/**")

public class RouteController...

Answer (score 0):

Add in to Spring security configuration file:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
       .authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers(
           "/registration**",
           "/js/**",
           "/css/**",
           "/img/**",
           "/webjars/**").permitAll()
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .and()
       .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login")
       .permitAll()
       .and()
       .logout()
       .invalidateHttpSession(true)
       .clearAuthentication(true)
       .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
       .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
       .permitAll();
}

and go to page HTML or jsp page 
like this 

 href="css/style.css">
```